# MySQL.exe, cannot login to gain access, 1064 ERROR with Syntax

Tags: mysql, database

This is the command I am typing into the MySQL interpreter, according to the docs:

```
mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password
```

So my version is:

```
mysql --user=root --password=something
```

I get a 1064 Syntax error saying I typed it wrong. I don't know what to do! I can log into phpMyAdmin correctly and all!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

mysql -uroot -psomething 
Would do it

Comment: You are already inside the interpreter. This command is used to get to where you are. You need to read a basic mysql book.

Answer (score 0):

you are already in mysql console, and this is not mysql command.
You should run this command in system shell, telling mysql client to use given username and password. But I guess you don't need it since default login and no password works.